# Rails 3.1 - how to update CSS styles

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

I have an app in Rails 3.1 and when I whatever change in the **application.css**, so these changes are not applied on the page.

Is here something else than in Rails 3?

Comment: are you using the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

From Rails 3.1, compiled assets are written to the location specified in `config.assets.prefix`. You must use the below task either during deployment or on localhost, if you do not have write access to your production filesystem:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You can configure your app for faster asset precompiles. To do this, you can partially load your application by setting `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` to be set to false in your `config/application.rb`. However, you should note that in this case, templates cannot see application objects or methods. Heroku requires this to be set to false so if you're running your app there, you should probably do this.

Comment: How do i undo this action? I applied it and now I need to run this every time to update my css in development mode

Comment: I think I found the answer myself. I just had to delete the compiled assets from the assets folder in the public directory. Please correct me if this is wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the application in production mode? if so you will need to precompile the assests ( rake assests:precompile ) and to restart your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this too.

A little poking around reveals that when you run rake assets:precompile, as part of its process it writes an application.css file into your public folder.

It seems that it is the application.css in the public directory that is being served on subsequent requests instead of the ones in the asset folder that you are working on.

If you delete the application.css file in the public directory you should be able to see you updates to the CSS when you reload the page.

I hope that helps.